# WordPress WP_Query custom order_by post_type functionality

Tags: wordpress

I'm on WordPress 6.2.2. I’ve got a query which retrieves content for a given meta value.

```
$query_posts_for_board_game = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'post_type' => ['reviews','articles', 'topics'],
        'posts_per_page' => 5,
        'meta_query' => array(
           // left empty for brevity
        ),
    )
);
```

Which returns the following list:

```
Expanding Everdell: A Ranking <-- article
Everdell Digital Game Review <-- review
Board Games with Animeeples <-- topic
Everdell Newleaf & Mistwood Game Video Review <-- review
Everdell Game Review <-- review
```

[image: Example of current sort order]

I’d like to force reviews to be first in the list, then articles, then topics. I know that I can adjust the order by adding this to my query:

```
'orderby' => 'post_type',
'order' => 'desc',
```

But that puts topics before reviews in reverse alphabetical order. Does PHP / WordPress allow us to use a dynamic orderby statement? Here's a link to the page in question if you want to see more examples: `https://www.meeplemountain.com/trending-board-games/`

Comment: You may also want to ask this question on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Oh! I always forget about that one, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

No `'orderby' => 'post_type'`.
Use this instead of `'orderby' => 'type'`.
[#order-orderby-parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters)

Comment: @imvhost I'm already able to order by type/post_type. I can make sure that Articles come before Reviews which come before Topics. But I'm looking for a way to force Reviews to come first (alphabetically), which I think will require some custom functionality.

Answer (score 0):

While I still think there's a better way, the way I ended up doing it was to split my query into two parts. I'm running a query to get just `reviews`, another query to `articles` and `topics` (in ascending order so that articles come first), then `array_merge`-ing the two queries together. Since I'm storing the combined array in a transient, the results are just as fast once it gets cached.